# Ember - Page not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying my first ember application. It has two pages. One is the Welcome page and the other page lists student details. so I have created two routes namely **index** and **studentdb**. The problem is my second page is not getting displayed. I have used **Mirage** as I am following ember guides. The code is as below:

**templates/index.hbs**

```
<h1> Welcome </h1>

{{#link-to "studentdb"}}List{{/link-to}}

{{outlet}}
```

**templates/studentdb.hbs**

```
<h2> Welcome to Student Database </h2>
<h4> Following are the details </h4>

{{#each model as |student|}}
  <p>Name: {{student.Name}}</p>
  <p>College: {{student.College}}</p>
  <p>Department: {{student.Department}}</p>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

**routes/studentdb.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('student');
    }
});
```

**models/student.js (model)**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  Name: DS.attr(),
  College: DS.attr(),
  Department: DS.attr()
});
```

**mirage/config.js**

```
export default function() {

  this.get('/student', function() {
    return {
      data: [{
        type: 'student',
        id: 1,
        attributes: {
          Name: 'Archana',
          College: 'MNM Jain',
          Department: 'CSE'

        }
      }, {
        type: 'student',
        id: 2,
        attributes: {
          Name: 'Monica',
          College: 'Sathyabama',
          Department: 'IT'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'student',
        id: 3,
        attributes: {
          Name: 'Manoj',
          College: 'Kumarsaamy',
          Department: 'MECH'
        }
      }]
    }
  });


}
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('studentdb');
});

export default Router;
```

Kindly someone help. Thanks in advance.

This the error I get after re-installing ember as given in the below instructions 
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

> npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is no longer
>   maintained. See its readme for upgrade details. npm ERR! registry
>   error parsing json npm ERR! registry error parsing json npm ERR!
>   registry error parsing json npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "ember-cli@2.2.0-beta.3"npm ERR! npm ERR! If you need help, you may
>   report this error at: npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\learner\npm-debug.lo

Kindly help please.

Comment: I think you need to also post `Router.map` code

Comment: I have included router file now

Comment: try specifying path `this.route('studentdb', { path: 'studentdb' });`

Comment: I tried but still getting a blank page.. I removed all the contents in **studentdb.hbs** and also **studentdb.js**  gave just a welcome message in **studentdb.hbs**, it is working fine. So the problem is with the model.

Comment: any errors on console when you navigate to `/studentdb` ?

Comment: Mirage: Your Ember app tried to GET '/students', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?                This is what I get in the console

Comment: which version of mirage you are using ?

Comment: if you are using 0.2.0-beta.1 switch to stable version 0.1.1 should help

Comment: How to find mirage version ?

Comment: package.json file :)

Comment: 0.1.11 is the mirage version

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your route `this.get('/students'`, it uses [ember-inflector](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector) internally to pluralize your urls this is according to [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org)

Comment: I am trying to understand it as I am just starting with ember ... i don't know what is ember-inflector

Comment: `ember-inflector` is just plurization/singularization library, given a word it pluralizes/singularizes the word

Comment: I changed this.get('/students,function()... now I am getting **<h2> Welcome to Student Database </h2>
<h4> Following are the details </h4>** these two lines displayed..but not the details

Comment: do you use ember inspector ? you can inspect that route if it has models etc. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ember as well and had the same problem. The issue below from github helped me realize that the guides I was following were newer than the version of ember-cli I had installed on my system:

https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/422

So, I chose to update ember to version 2.2.0-beta.3 using these instructions:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

After that, I also had to re-install ember-cli-mirage, but then it worked!

Comment: Hi.. Yes even I thought that might be the problem. But did not know a solution. Your answered helped me..I tried those instructions. When re-installed the ember ..I am getting error. and it has not been installed..can you help me please. I have updated my question with the error that I get.